# Read Time Out process

Tags: c#, timeout, embedded-resource, disassembly

Kindly answer this

ildasm screenshot

.mresource public LinkDev.BSolutions.ExchangeValidationLib.ExchangeValidationTemplate.html

I am trying to access this resource from my code:

```
Stream templateStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(typeof(MailManager), templateName)
```

but the result always become `null` 
.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it returns null because resource cannot be found.
You need to make sure that following is correct:

1. You are executing this code in assembly which contains this resource.
2. Namespace of *MailManager* matches namespace of resource -**LinkDev.BSolutions.ExchangeValidationLib**
3. templateName must be equal to **"ExchangeValidationTemplate.html"**